# Android Studio build errors not pointing me to the actual compile error

Tags: android-studio

When using kotlin and I have a compile error in my code, the Android Studio build log does not point me to that compile error in my code, it just gives me this (and more that points nowhere in my code):

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
```

But if I run

```
./gradlew clean build
```

the error output from that in my terminal points me to my file containing the compile error.

Can I do something to make Android studio report this error correctly also?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Preferences > Build, Execution , Deployment > Compiler. Fil Command-line options field with below.

--stacktrace

And then click OK.

Or try using your Debugger